# ShareActionProvider not clickable?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a ShareActionProvider in my ActionBar and I've followed google's example for it to the tee. I'm curious why it's not clickable?

EDIT: I know that if I remove the shareHistory function it becomes clickable but I don't want to keep shared history.

xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share" />
```

Java code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_legislation, menu);

    MenuItem item = (MenuItem)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS, "http://www.anilinkz.com/");

    mSharedActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)item.getActionProvider();

    setShareIntent(sharingIntent);

    return true;
}

public void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mSharedActionProvider != null) {
        mSharedActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        mSharedActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ACTION_ALL_APPS` is an `Intent` action. It is not a key to an extra, and `ACTION_ALL_APPS` is not a part of the `ACTION_SEND` protocol. Beyond that, perhaps the device or emulator that you are testing has nothing that supports `ACTION_SEND` of `text/plain`, though that would be unusual.

Comment: I'm testing against a galaxy s4. The only reason I did ACTION_ALL_APPS was to appease facebook since they don't allow EXTRA_TEXT. It doesn't work with EXTRA_TEXT either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_legislation, menu);

    MenuItem item = (MenuItem)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.anilinkz.com/");

    mSharedActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    setShareIntent(sharingIntent);

    return true;
}

public void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mSharedActionProvider != null) {
        mSharedActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: the only thing you did was remove setShareFileHistoryName()... I don't want the shared History. It does make it clickable, but I already knew that :(
I'll edit my post, thanks!